# What is the Linux equivalent to Windows \\ folder route path?

Tags: debian, software-installation, directory-structure, node.js

We have some route path in our project like this line:

```
"start": "set NODE_ENV=local&&node_modules\\.bin\\webpack --config webpack.dev.config.js"
```

How is the equivalent in Linux? We are using Debian but we have problems using this alternatives:

```
"start": "set NODE_ENV=local&&node_modules//.bin//webpack --config webpack.dev.config.js"
```

or:

```
"start": "set NODE_ENV=local&&node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.dev.config.js"
```

Comment: This is a Unix forum, what does \\ do in Windows?

Comment: Is the `&&` part of the path?

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing to do with Linux or with path separators, which you have already adjusted.

> ```
> set NODE_ENV=local
> ```

This is not how to set an environment variable in a POSIX shell.

> ```
> &&
> ```

This is not how to run a command with a nonce environment variable setting in a POSIX shell.

You need to learn the basics of POSIX shell scripting, including how to set variables.

I'd say look at something like `cross-env` but that actually presumes that one already knows POSIX shell scripting, because it makes things work in POSIX-shell-like fashion on Windows:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=local node_modules/.bin/webpack …
```

You need to learn POSIX shell scripting in the first place before that.

```
NODE_ENV=local node_modules/.bin/webpack …
```

This sort of thing is not specific to Linux (an operating system kernel) or even to Debian.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question:

Since backslash is the scape character, when you are going to put it in a string you need to scape it by another backslash. So double backslash simply means a single backslash.

In linux you use forward slash to separate path, so  there is no need to double it.

So to convert a path from Windows to Linux format, just replace any double backslash with a forward slash.

But for the rest of the command, you need to give more info like where is this and what you are going to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux equivalant of Windows double-<reverse solidus> is "//".

Section 4.13 Pathname Resolution of the Base Definitions volume says:

> ... If a pathname begins with two successive  characters, the first component following the leading  characters may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading  characters shall be treated as a single  character. ...

So, on some system, it may get interpreted as host name.

However, that only applies to the 1st component of the path string. For the rest of the string, it's the same as single-"/", check with the documentation of your configuration file.